# Run tests using Behat and Mink Selenium2 driver for Microsoft Edge browser in Selenium 4

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

Is it possible to run tests on Edge browser using Mink Selenium2 driver and Selenium 4 grid ?

I've tried using:

```
default:
    suites:
      default:
        filters:
          tags: ~@wip
        paths: ['%paths.base%/storage/features']
    gherkin:
      cache: ~
    extensions:
      Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: http://www.google.com
        javascript_session: selenium2
        browser_name: edge
        selenium2:
          capabilities:
            browserName: MicrosoftEdge
            browser: edge
            extra_capabilities:
              edgeOptions:
                args:
                  - "--no-sandbox"
                  - "--disable-dev-shm-usage"
                  - "--headless"
                  - "--disable-gpu"
                  - "--dns-prefetch-disable"
                  - "--disable-setuid-sandbox"
                  - "--window-size=1920,1080"
                  - "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
```

But this gives me some errors saying that the DevToolsActivePort file does not exist:

````
13:38:41.079 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
13:38:41.086 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
13:38:41.942 INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 8 available processors
13:38:41.970 INFO [NodeOptions.discoverDrivers] - Discovered 3 driver(s)
13:38:41.997 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Edge for {"browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"} 8 times
13:38:41.999 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Chrome for {"browserName": "chrome"} 8 times
13:38:42.000 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Firefox for {"browserName": "firefox"} 8 times
13:38:42.039 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: id, relative, name
13:38:42.067 INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node fb3c75f0-847d-475d-88b0-dea6893c09c2 at http://172.19.0.7:4444. Health check every 120s
13:38:42.068 INFO [GridModel.setAvailability] - Switching node fb3c75f0-847d-475d-88b0-dea6893c09c2 (uri: http://172.19.0.7:4444) from DOWN to UP
13:38:42.251 INFO [Standalone.execute] - Started Selenium Standalone 4.0.0 (revision 3a21814679): http://172.19.0.7:4444

Starting MSEdgeDriver 95.0.1020.30 (09f7018e2a65a55dea3a0a261efca40ae03471ed) on port 36979
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping MSEdgeDriver safe.
MSEdgeDriver was started successfully.
[1634828868.563][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
15:07:48.749 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$0] - {"traceId": "49c55d39b0c26898585047f89ad32f33","eventTime": 1634828868685689900,"eventName": "exception","attributes": {"driver.url": "http:\u002f\u002flocalhost:36979","exception.message": "Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: MSEdge failed to start: exited abnormally.\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from msedge location \u002fusr\u002fbin\u002fmicrosoft-edge is no longer running, so MSEdgeDriver is assuming that MSEdge has crashed.)\nBuild info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'\nSystem info: host: 'dee4c77efe99', ip: '172.19.0.7', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.25-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.11'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown","exception.stacktrace": "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: MSEdge failed to start: exited abnormally.\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from msedge location \u002fusr\u002fbin\u002fmicrosoft-edge is no longer running, so MSEdgeDriver is assuming that MSEdge has crashed.)\nBuild info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'\nSystem info: host: 'dee4c77efe99', ip: '172.19.0.7', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.25-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.11'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply(DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:131)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply(DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:65)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot.apply(SessionSlot.java:143)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.newSession(LocalNode.java:315)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.startSession(LocalDistributor.java:513)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.newSession(LocalDistributor.java:440)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.handleNewSessionRequest(LocalDistributor.java:648)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.lambda$run$1(LocalDistributor.java:612)\n\tat java.base\u002fjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base\u002fjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base\u002fjava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n","exception.type": "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException","logger": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory","session.capabilities": "{\"browserName\": \"MicrosoftEdge\"}\n"}}```
````

is there any way to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have

127.0.0.1 localhost
in your /etc/hosts file.

To check it, you should go to the terminal and run

sudo vi /etc/hosts
type your user password and paste

127.0.0.1 localhost
to an empty row.

Additionally, please make sure you have ChromeDriver -or the driver of the browser you intend to use- is installed and your program knows the path of ChromeDriver.

You can follow the steps explained here https://www.browserstack.com/guide/run-selenium-tests-using-selenium-chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

1. For DevToolsActivePort error try another workaround: add --remote-debugging-port=
2. I tried a different version of Selenium server with Edge, including version 4, till version 3.5; it is working fine, and above, it gives different errors. I can see that Selenium 4 is in alpha release at the Maven repository, and all other versions were released in October 2021. I would recommend that you use an earlier version for some time. You can refer to [this article](https://www.programsbuzz.com/article/behat-launch-microsoft-edge-browser-using-mink-selenium2driver) for the configuration of Edge with Behat Mink Selenium 2.